# How to refer to a Cell in Excel when i specify Column directly but use formula instead of specifying row number directly

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

Short summary, to refer to the cell C5, rather than saying =C5 , i need to use =C(a+b) , because the row number is variable and calculated using a formula, but the reference =C(a+b) doesn't work.

In Microsoft Excel, I am using =MATCH(A1, B:B, 0) to get the row number at which the value at A1 exists in Column B. For eg it returns 5. How do i refer to Column C and Row[returnedValue] i.e. C5 if i am writing the formula in one line? i.e. i tried using 
 =C(MATCH(A1, B:B,0)) to refer to Column C and Row 5 , but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The **INDIRECT** function will do this for you.

To Test ...

1. Put the words "This is a test" in cell A1.
2. In cell A2, put the text "1"
3. In cell A3, put this formula ...

   ```
   ="A" & A2
   ```
4. Finally, in cell A4, add this formula ...

   ```
   =INDIRECT(A3)
   ```

... that should then return the text within A1.

This demonstrates how it works so you should be able to apply it to your scenario.  I suspect something like this will work for you?!? ...

```
="C" & (MATCH(A1, B:B,0))
```

... barring additional error checking of course.